# Group Arrays based on their Elements

Tags: java, arrays

im currently working on a code to group Arrays based on their Elements and i hope u can help me out with your wisdom.

I have given following Arrays:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "F", "I"));
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("B", "C", "D", "E", "F"));
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("J", "K", "B", "L", "F"));
List<String> list4 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("L", "K", "D", "C", "J"));
```

Now i want to compare which of these lists have 3 Elements in common and save that ListNames in a new List/Array.

```
commonList1{List2, List3,}       - (B,C,F)
commonList4{List5}               - (K,J,L)
```

Has anyone a smarter idea for doing that, instead of running through all Lists, compare each with another and search how many lists have the same intersection?

Best wishes
Tom

Comment: Best off using a `set`

Comment: At least the naive `Set` implementation would be faster. Therefore collect each into its own set, then compute the set intersections like you would do it with arrays. The advantage, `Set` can answer `contains` in `O(1)` (fast) (at least on the average).

Comment: IMHO duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36110216/1828296

Comment: @lospejos I already looked at that thread, the problem is, that if im doing in in that ways, I only get the common elements of all Lists. But I would like to group the lists, where atleast 3 elements are in common. Soryy if my question was unclear in that point

Comment: The problem is not well-defined unless you specify which intersection set you are interested in.  Lists `a` and `b` could have a common intersection of 3 elements, and lists `b` and `c` could have an intersection set of 3 different elements.

Comment: Correct, I edited it therefore.

Comment: `list1.retainAll(list2); // listA now contains only the elements which are also contained in listB.`

Answer (score 1):

```
listA.retainAll(listB);
```

listA holds the elements which are also contained in listB.
To avoid changing listA, then you need to create a new list.

```
List<Integer> common = new ArrayList<Integer>(listA);
common.retainAll(listB);
```

The code above allows you to keep from changing listA or listB and common now contains only the elements which are contained in listA and listB.

Comment: You just copied and pasted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943330/common-elements-in-two-lists#answer-5943349). Also, you didn't copy the information properly with links. Please make it comment or link the OP to proper documentations.